# Electron forge - Resource file name with wrong charset

Tags: electron, electron-forge, charset

I use Electron Forge to build an Windows App. But after installing it, it appears to have some errors. And for some debugging, I found out that some of my resource file's name were turned into something like this `������` (it only happens when the file name contains triditional chinese charecters). After I manually renamed the file from the app's resource folder, it works as it usually does.

The following picture is what it looks like in my file explore.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4BXC.png)

And This one is what it **SHOULD** look like. (only the chinese part)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x18an.png)

I've tried this in windows 10 and 11.

And I wonder if there is a way to choose the correct charset (o anything) when building the app, so I don't have to MANUALLY rename the files after install.

When I use `npm run start` this doesn't happen. So I think it is the building part's problem.